# using javascript replace() to match the last occurance of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, coffeescript

I'm building an 'add new row' function for product variations, and I'm struggling with the regex required to match the form attribute keys. So, I'm basically cloning rows, then incrementing the keys, like this (coffeescript):

```
  newrow = oldrow.find('select, input, textarea').each ->
    this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, (str, p1) ->
      "[" + (parseInt(p1, 10) + 1) + "]"
    )
    this.id = this.id.replace(/\_(\d+)\_/, (str, p1) ->
      "_" + (parseInt(p1, 10) + 1) + "_"
    )
  .end()
```

This correctly increments a field with a name of `product[variations][1][name]`, turning it into `product[variations][2][name]`

BUT Each variation can have multiple options (eg, color can be red, blue, green), so I need to be able turn this `product[variations][1][options][2][name]` into `product[variations][1][options][3][name]`, leaving the variation key alone. What regex do I need to match only the last occurrence of a key (the options key)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead for that:

```
/\[(\d+)\](?!.*\[\d+\])/
```

The `(?!_____)` part is the negative lookahead.

What that says is: Match and capture digits between square brackets only if there are no digits in square brackets later in the string. [Live Explanation](http://regex101.com/r/pI5dB8/1)

```
var m = "product[variations][1][options][3][name]".match(/\[(\d+)\](?!.*\[\d+\])/);
console.log(m[1]); // "3"
```

Comment: I've been stuck on this for 3 hours and you fix it in 2 minutes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

sometimes I like use split also if possible :

```
var a = 'product[variations][1][options][2][name]'.split('][');
// you can then replace before last value :
a[a.length-2] = indexYouWish;
var newName = a.join('][');
```